# How can I create unique id's for jQuery widget instances?

Tags: jquery, widget, unique, instance

I am creating a rich text editor based on jQuery widget, and it can have multiple instances on a page. The first instance should generate a toolbar like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bold-1"><label for="bold-1">..
<input type="checkbox" id="italic-1"><label for="italic-1">..
...
```

The second instance should generate:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bold-2"><label for ="bold-2">..
<input type="checkbox" id="italic-2"><label for ="italic-2">..
```

The labels 'for' attribute need to uniquely refer to their corresponding input 'id' attribute. Therefore I need to add a unique id for each instance.

Something like this could work but I dont like to store a counter in global namespace:

```
var textEditorCount;
$.widget("myEditor.textEditor", {
   _create: function () {
      textEditorCount = textEditorCount ? textEditorCount + 1 : 1;
      this.instanceID = textEditorCount;
   },
   ...
};
```

Maybe the question boils down to: (How) can I store a variable in the namespace of the widget?

Comment: Personally I would create global jquery array holding reference to all of my plugin instances. Then you can use .length to get number of them and easily reference needed one.

Comment: @fliespl You solution does work, but is a bit more than I need. My problem is not so much how to bind the button to the widget instance, but how to create a 'for' tag in the label that refers uniquely to an input id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since jQuery UI 1.9 each widget instance has unique fields `this.uuid` and `this.eventNamespace`:

```
this.uuid = uuid++;
this.eventNamespace = "." + this.widgetName + this.uuid;
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.9.0/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L215

Field `this.eventNamespace` is suitable for assigning/clearing unique event handlers (http://api.jquery.com/on/ - read chapter 'Event names and namespaces').

Comment: Thanks Victor, definitely the better solution

Answer (score 6):

You can use a closure:

```
(function () {
  var textEditorCount;
  $.widget("myEditor.textEditor", {
     _create: function () {
        textEditorCount = textEditorCount ? textEditorCount + 1 : 1;
        this.instanceID = textEditorCount;
     },
     ...
  };
})();
```

`textEditorCount` is not going to be global anymore.

Comment: Wow, yes of course. I have that closure already there, I just didn't think about declaring the variable there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Global Var ( or in NS) Up one every instance
that is what i do

Comment: so the remaining question is, how do I do that in the namespace. Can I just do: $.myNamespace.textEditorCount += 1; ? It seems to work, but I don't know if it is legal / advisable.